# How to cross compile linux arm to x86

Tags: c++, x86, arm, cross-compiling, apple-m1

I'm using an m1 pro macbook pro.
Up until now, I used intel macbook.

My program is written in c/c++ and the target is ubuntu x86_64.

I tried running ubuntu x86 docker (qemu) and it's super slow - to the point it's unusable.
I have linux ubuntu (arm) installed using parallels and would like to compile for x86 target instead of arm.

How do I do it?

Comment: It is compiler dependent, which compiler are you using?

Comment: I don't know about Apple, but on Linux systems you can typically install a specific cross-compiler for the target system. Maybe take a look in your repository?

Comment: Use a compiler that can target Ubuntu x86.  The `g++` compiler has many variations.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, I would suggest an `apt install gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu g++-x86-64-linux-gnu`, and then invoking the installed compiler with the `x86-64-linux-gnu` prefix (for gcc, `x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc`) to create x86_64 binaries.

Do note that if you target x86_64 you won't be able to run the programs you build natively, but you should be able to package the binaries created for execution on an x86_64 machine.

Comment: Here, the command is `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` (replace `-` with `_`)

Answer (score 1):

Install docker-desktop on your mac and run this docker container with the command:

```
docker container run --platform=linux/amd64 -it -p 6080:6080 -e WIDTH=1920 -e HEIGHT=1080 yoas1/xubuntu-desktop:1.0
```

Don't forget to create volume to the code directory.
In your browser go to: http://localhost:6080/vnc.html to access the xubuntu desktop

[Image on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/yoas1/xubuntu-desktop)

Comment: http://localhost:6080/vnc.html is a local link, not something people can access

Comment: @phuclv: After running that `docker` command, with that ports opened up, it should be accessible from the same computer.  Looks like the edit following your comment was an improvement, showing the text of the link instead of just having it as a hyperlink behind some other text.  Indeed that was weird.